# Generating power-law degree-distributed random directed graphs

Tags: python, networkx

I searched for generating random directed graphs $G(V,E)$ with a specific node and edge count, specified in and out degree distributions, without loops and fully connected. I found a function in R in [this link](http://igraph.org/r/doc/static.power.law.game.html).

I searched in networkx, but found only [this function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.generators.directed.scale_free_graph.html#networkx.generators.directed.scale_free_graph), where the graph grows by preferential attachment and hence the number of edges is not controllable.

Is there an equivalent to the R function in Python?

Comment: For that igraph function - it's not at all clear to me from the documentation that the result is connected.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, it may not be a connected graph, but if the no. of edges is high enough, I usually end up with one.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be so easy to generate a graph like that (fixed number of edges, nodes, degree distribution, connected)....
But the directed configuration model might get you mostly there.
http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.directed_configuration_model.html#networkx.generators.degree_seq.directed_configuration_model

> Return a directed_random graph with the given degree sequences.
>
> The configuration model generates a random directed pseudograph (graph
>   with parallel edges and self loops) by randomly assigning edges to
>   match the given degree sequences.

The example shows how to remove self-loops and parallel edges.

```
>>> D=nx.DiGraph([(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]) # directed path graph
>>> din=list(D.in_degree().values())
>>> dout=list(D.out_degree().values())
>>> din.append(1)
>>> dout[0]=2
>>> D=nx.directed_configuration_model(din,dout)
To remove parallel edges:

>>> D=nx.DiGraph(D)
To remove self loops:

>>> D.remove_edges_from(D.selfloop_edges())
```

You will need to generate both an in-degree and out-degree sequence of your specified length and sum as inputs.  If you remove self-loop edges and parallel edges that will likely reduce the number of edges from your original specification.

Also no guarantee your graph will be connected.